# How can I use turn by turn navigation in Google Map in Android or what can I use for turn by turn navigation?

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed an app which uses Google Map. I already wrote for `getDirections` using google map direction API. I am getting LatLng List. But I don't know how can I implement turn by turn navigation like in navigation apps or Uber into my app using Google Map. Or what can I use for this in my app? I am setting marker and polyLine but can't use turn by turn navigation

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In section 10.4.c of the google maps API privacy terms [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/).

It states

> No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b)
>   automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

So no, it is not possible to create a turn-by-turn navigation application on android by using Google Maps API without breaching their privacy policy. Your best bet would be to forward the long & lat to the devices native maps app or waze your choice!

Comment: What can I use then for turn by turn navigation

Comment: I would take a look at this list ```https://www.igismap.com/top-10-map-direction-api-routing-libraries-navigation-free-or-paid/```

Comment: I will try MapBox from these

Comment: @mirzemehdi How was MapBox ?

Comment: @Noman it was easy to develop with MapBox

Answer (score 2):

You can use Here maps for turn-by-turn navigation.

In **Here-Maps SDK**, NavigationManager class is responsible for providing voice and visual instructions to the user while driving or walking. An instance of NavigationManager can be retrieved using NavigationManager.getInstance(). It should be associated with a map with setMap(Map) method before navigation is started.

Navigation can be started in three different modes:
Simulation Mode - simulate(Route, long) - This mode does not require any GPS data from the device as the position is simulated along the given route.
Navigation Mode - startNavigation(Route) - This mode takes the calculated route and matches the position against the route. Before using this mode, PositioningManager is required to be running with GPS data.
Tracking Mode - startTracking() - This mode does not require a calculated route as it only tracks and shows the current position on the map.

You can find examples that demonstrate the navigation feature in Turn by Turn Navigation and Advanced Navigation projects at https://github.com/heremaps/.

source : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance.html